# Tyring to define a macro that results in quotes around value of a previous #define value without escaping quotes

Tags: macros, escaping

I embedded assembly code in C++ source using asm()statement. This is used on a micro-controller where exact timing is needed in some places. By embedding, instead of having a separate file for assembly code, I can share symbols created using #define.

I current do things like this (Successfully)

> #define ARRAYSIZE 40
>
> #define ARRAYSIZE_ASM "40"

then I use ARRAYSIZE in C++ and ARRAYSIZE_ASM within asm()

(note that whitespace around number also works. e.g.  ARRAYSIZE_ASM " 40 "

I want to avoid having two places to update ( 40 and "40" ) to ease maintenance and make using command line -D practical.

If this were used only by compiler I could do

> #define ARRAYSIZE 40
>
> #define ARRAYSIZE_ASM "\"" ARRAYSIZE "\""

But the asm() statement passes the escapes to the assembler to parse, and it gets quite angry.

I would like to define ARRAYSIZE_ASM using a macro, but it is over my head.

> #define ellusivemacro(x)  <HELP ME PLEASE>
>
> #define ARRAYSIZE 40
>
> #define ARRAYSIZE_ASM   ellusivemacro(ARRAYSIZE)

If any of you could help me with such a macro, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks
Rob

Comment: Have you experimented with the [Stringizing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/stringizing-operator-hash?view=msvc-170)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in good direction. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David. Stringizing operator works great for this !

```
#define QADD(x) #x
#define QUOTEIT(x) QADD(x)
#define ARRAYSIZE 40
#define ARRAYSIZE_ASM QUOTEIT(ARRAYSIZE)
```

Comment: Glad you found an answer that works for you.  If you are using gcc or clang, there are other ways of passing integer constants to your asm (consider using the 'i' [constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints) for example) with your [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) code.